# Stop javascript from executing

Tags: javascript

I know this is simple but I cant get the conditional if below to work...

This line below " if ( !$section.id == "no-transition" ) " is not correct.

I'm trying to stop javascript from working on section elements that have the id of "no-transition".

Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
function initEvents() {

    $sections.each( function() {

            var $section = $( this );

            if ( !$section.id == "no-transition" ) { 
            // expand the clicked section and scale down the others
            $section.on( 'click', function() {

                    [code taken out to shorten post...]

                    if( !supportTransitions ) {
                            $section.removeClass( 'bl-expand-top' );
                    }

                    $el.removeClass( 'bl-expand-item' );

                    return false;

            } );
           }
} );
```

Comment: You *really* should not have multiple elements with the same id on a page. Its baad!

Comment: This is why you should always use `!=` and never `!... ==`. :)

Comment: You have syntax error in your code. Where is the `}` for the function?

Comment: To be more clear about why you should not have the same id for multiple elements: the `id` attribute is not built to have the same value assigned to multiple elements. If you attempt to `.getElementById` or use some kind of jQuery event handler like `$('#no-transition').click(...` it will only return/be applied to the first element.  If you want to act on multiple elements, use a shared `class` attribute value.

Comment: if I changed it to a class what would the corresponding conditional if be?    if ($section.attr('class') != "no-transition")    ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You really should not have multiple elements with the same id on a page.*

Your *if* condition should be modified to:

```
...
if ( $section.attr('id') != "no-transition" ) { 
   ...
```

Comment: Superb techfoobar! I apologize I didn't have enough javascript experience to get this one right. Thanks for everyone's comments.